How does \vdotswithin work?
The following code produces aligned equations.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
a_{11}x_1&+a_{12}x_2&+\ldots&+a_{1n}x_n&&=b_1\\
a_{21}x_1&+a_{22}x_2&+\ldots&+a_{2n}x_n&&=b_2\\
&\vdotswithin{+}&\vdotswithin{+}&&&\vdotswithin{=}\\
a_{m1}x_1&+a_{m2}x_2&+\ldots&+a_{mn}x_n&&=b_m
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}

This is how the result looks like.

The middle \vdotswithin{+} controls where the middle vertical dots should be. I would expect the vertical dots to be aligned below the second + in the equation since the command is \vdotswithin{+} but instead the vertical dots are aligned below \ldots. If I replace + with \ldots, the middle vertical dots get shifted to the left and they are not aligned with anything as far as I can see.
Why does \vdotswithin{+} align the vertical dots below \ldots even though the vertical dots are supposed to be aligned below +? I hope my question makes sense.
Any help is much appreciated!

You have the wrong number of alignment columns. It should be 4 not 3. And you have the wrong number of &'s per line. It should be 2 × <alignment cols> -1. So 7 here.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
a_{11}x_1 & +a_{12}x_2      && +\cdots         && +a_{1n}x_n && =b_1            \\
a_{21}x_1 & +a_{22}x_2      && +\cdots         && +a_{2n}x_n && =b_2            \\
          & \vdotswithin{+} && \vdotswithin{+} &&            && \vdotswithin{=} \\
a_{m1}x_1 & +a_{m2}x_2      && +\cdots         && +a_{mn}x_n && =b_m
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}

In your example the cdots col was right aligned and thus looked like it was centered under the dots.


No need to load amsmath in addition to mathtools, right? :-)

@Mico I always load both. A lot of peope think mathtools is a successor to math tools. So it is better to know what exactly one is loading. Plus I did not change the OPs preamble.

Should read "... think mathtools is a successor to mathtools... ". It is more of a companion

I tend to think of mathtools as a superset rather than as a successor of amsmath. Is that a fair label?

@Mico, perhaps, just wanted to fix the typo in my comment

The idea behind \vdotswithin{<symbol>} was to align (horizontally) a \vdots within the width of the <symbol>. So, it does not search for the <symbol> within your align construction and align it with that; you need to ensure the use of it is at the same spot where you want it to occur.
In the mathtools documentation, the following example is used:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \framebox[1.5cm]{}
    &= \framebox[3cm]{} \\
    & \vdots            \\
    &= \framebox[3cm]{} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}

In the above code, \vdots is placed exactly where the other = signs occur. However, it's obviously offset horizontally because the different operators (symbols) have different widths. So, being at the correct location, using \vdotswidth{=} places the \vdots within a box of appropriate width - the width of {}={} (the additional surrounding brace groups provide the appropriate spacing around operators; they differ depending on whether it's an atom, a binary operator or a relation):

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \framebox[1.5cm]{}
    &= \framebox[3cm]{} \\
    & \vdotswithin{=}   \\
    &= \framebox[3cm]{} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}

So, in your setup, you need to first ensure that the \vdots you want to place is at the correct horizontal location before using \vdotswithin{<symbol>}. This can be done in many ways.

Using your original setup (fewer alignment points) in via alignat together with some spacing adjustments:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  %       R & L              &                                R & L           &R& L
  a_{11}x_1 & + a_{12}x_2    &                          + \dots & + a_{1n}x_n & & = b_1           \\
  a_{21}x_1 & + a_{22}x_2    &                          + \dots & + a_{2n}x_n & & = b_2           \\
            &\vdotswithin{+} & \vdotswithin{\!+}\phantom{\dots} &             & & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  a_{m1}x_1 & + a_{m2}x_2    &                          + \dots & + a_{mn}x_n & & = b_m
\end{alignat*}

For clarity, I've added R (for Right) or L (for Left) in the first commented line of the above alignat, showing which side the alignment takes place.
Because of the R vs L alignment switch between the first two terms in each row/equation, the horizontal alignment seems off for the second terms - they have different widths.


Using more alignment points via alignat (taken from daleif's post):
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  %       R & L                &R& L               &R& L           &R& L
  a_{11}x_1 & + a_{12}x_2      & & + \dots         & & + a_{1n}x_n & & = b_1           \\
  a_{21}x_1 & + a_{22}x_2      & & + \dots         & & + a_{2n}x_n & & = b_2           \\
            & \vdotswithin{+}  & & \vdotswithin{+} & &             & & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  a_{m1}x_1 & + a_{m2}x_2      & & + \dots         & & + a_{mn}x_n & & = b_m
\end{alignat*}


This has a similar Right-then-Left alignment of some of the terms, so some people may find it odd.

Using more alignments via alignat with similar alignments for terms
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  %       R & L               &         R & L     &                   R & L     &         R & L
  a_{11}x_1 & {}+{}           & a_{12}x_2 & {}+{} &           {}\dots{} & {}+{} & a_{1n}x_n & = b_1           \\
  a_{21}x_1 & {}+{}           & a_{22}x_2 & {}+{} &           {}\dots{} & {}+{} & a_{2n}x_n & = b_2           \\
            & \vdotswithin{+} &           &       & \vdotswithin{\dots} &       &           & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  a_{m1}x_1 & {}+{}           & a_{m2}x_2 & {}+{} &           {}\dots{} & {}+{} & a_{mn}x_n & = b_m
\end{alignat*}


The above example also shows \vdots aligned with the \dots. Additional {} elements around operators yield the appropriate spacing which is otherwise gobbled around the alignments &.

It's not a problem with \vdotswithin, but of alignat, at least how you're using it.
I'd use array for the job.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{
  r >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}c<{{}} c >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}c<{{}} l
}
a_{11}x_1 &+& a_{12}x_2 &+& \dotsb &+& a_{1n}x_n&&=b_1 \\
a_{21}x_1 &+& a_{22}x_2 &+& \dotsb &+& a_{2n}x_n&&=b_2 \\[-0.5ex]
&\vdots && \vdots &&\vdots \\
a_{m1}x_1 &+& a_{m2}x_2 &+& \dotsb &+& a_{mn}x_n&&=b_m
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}

Alignment points are more precisely selected this way and “counting &'s” is easier.

